# How can I constantly updating this time command?

Tags: python, time, discord.py

So I got this discord.py code:

```
import datetime
import pytz

dt_vn = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone("Asia/Saigon"))


@client.command()
async def time(ctx):
    while True:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Date", colour=discord.Colour.green())
        embed.add_field(name="Hour", value=dt_vn.strftime("%H"))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        sleep(1)
```

Basically, it shows what time it is now. But isn't updating, which means that if I repeat this command several times, it will still show the same time. Help me :((

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Answer (score 3):

Move the `dt_vn` assignment into the loop so it's updated for every message sent.

```
import datetime
import pytz

@client.command()
async def time(ctx):
    while True:
        dt_vn = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Asia/Saigon'))
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Date", colour=discord.Colour.green())
        embed.add_field(name="Hour", value = dt_vn.strftime('%H'))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: sorry but your code did not worked out for me

Comment: @averyniceprogrammer The code in the answer uses `sleep(1)` (as did your original code), that should be replace with `await asyncio.sleep(1)` as the normal `sleep()` is a blocking function that will halt your bot

Comment: @FierySpectre You can't tell whether `sleep()` is imported from `time` or `asyncio`, but if it was the latter, you'd need to await it, certainly.

Comment: Seeing as it isnt awaited I assumed it was the basic `time.sleep()`. `time.sleep()` isnt asynchronous so it will stop the bot from working at all.

Comment: @FierySpectre the `time.sleep()` is not working because it cannot recognise the `time` attribute in @command. But I did installed asyncio package so I might test it

Comment: And also if I put the dt_vn variable into that command, the command object cannot recognise the datetime attribute